# Can't view achieved silver badge

Tags: support, badges

Here it shows that **I have a silver badge**:
[image]

But not on the "Select Next Badge" page... (I can see my achieved bronze badges though)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all badges can be tracked.

This is by design - some badges are too expensive (performance wise) to track.

Comment: Can I at least know which silver badge I have please? :)

Comment: @DominatorX - all the badges you have are listed in the badges section of your activity page. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4272600/dominatorx?tab=badges

Comment: Status-bydesign?

Comment: @scriptHero - we don't normally add that tag to support questions.