# Badge and privilege progress bar fill is misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badge-progress, activity

If you zoom in close enough (pinch-zoom on a touchscreen), you can see that the fill for the Badge progress bar on the Activity page is not perfect.

[image: badge progress bar]

A bit less subtly on the Privileges bar:

[image: privilege progress bar]

[This problem is almost 1 year old.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255933/cant-view-achieved-silver-badge)

Comment: You won't notice it if you just glance at it.

Comment: @lolreppeatlol I would say the same about the endless number of "bug" reports about incorrect pluralization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress bar height was a pixel off from the container.

Fixed now and being deployed everywhere.